# SwiftUI navigationView within Modal 'pushing' view down

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, ios13, ios-navigationview

I currently have a modal view in ***SwiftUI*** that contains a series of NavigationLinks to different views. However, when I go to one of the other views it pushes all the content down leaving a empty forehead at the top of the view. How do I fix this?
I have included an example screenshot below.

[image]

To further clarify, there is a main view with a button that opens a Modal view. This modal contains a navigation view with a series of NavigationLink Buttons. When opening the navigation links within the modal, that is when the view is pushed down.

Comment: For getting better idea can you post code ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62806762/swiftui-destination-of-navigationlink-creates-view-with-extra-space
This one solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

You have a large navigation bar, try to set navigationBar displayMode to `.inline`

```
.navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
```

Comment: I tried this, and while it did center my views back to normal, it added a top bar with a different background color than the view it was in. Is there an easy way to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

This probably happens because the view you push to from the NavigationView is also wrapped in a NavigationView.

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
           NavigationLink(destination: IAPView()) {
               Text("In App Purchase")
           }
       }
    }
}
```

You probably have this in the IAPView()

```
struct IAPView: View {
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView { <-- this is causing it
               // your buttons here
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You still have the default navigation bar space in your view. You need to add **both** these two view modifiers.

```
.navigationBarTitle("")
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```